# Eclipse CDT indicates syntax error for operator defines

Tags: eclipse-cdt

At my company we use C defines like this:

```
#define AND                 &&
#define bwAND               &
```

When using this eclipse underlines the expression as if it had a syntax error.
How do I make it understand our logic operator defines?

Comment: I just tried this out on Galileo and it doesn't underline anything for me.

Comment: Okay, i'll try Galileo i'm still on Ganymede

Answer (score 0):

Your example works in Helios